# Custom radix columns (+special characters)

Tags: swift, string, numbers

Currently I'm using this code to convert a number into an **base36**-string:

```
let number = 300293338
let base36 = String(number, radix: 36);
print(base36) // 4ysbtm
```

But I'm wondering how it's possible to generate my own alphabet with a kind of a **Base10 to AnyBase conversion** using Swift.

An example of the alphabet could be something like this:

```
["$", "%", "&", "/", "(", "9", "=", "?", "+", "#", "-", ".", ">", "<", "*", "!", ...]
```

It maybe could look like this:

```
let number = 300293338
let base36 = mycoolfunction(number)
print(base36) // "$%//+#="
```

Comment: So you have a sort of "secret code" where the digit characters of a base 36 number's string are replaced by your own digit characters? Then just do what you are doing and then perform the digit string substitution of your characters for the original characters.

Comment: Well, that's kind of vague, wouldn't you say? I have no idea what "deal with ... 50" even means, and I suspect you don't either. If you cannot enunciate clearly the rules by which a number would be represented as a string under your imaginary "system", you cannot possibly write a computer program that carries out those rules. Conversely, if you _can_ enunciate the rules, the program is nine-tenths written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the basic base 10 to any base conversion, modified for custom digits:

```
func numberToCustomRadix(_ number: Int, alphabet: String) -> String {
    let base = alphabet.count
    var number = number
    var result = ""
    repeat {
        let idx = alphabet.index(alphabet.startIndex, offsetBy: number % base)
        result = [alphabet[idx]] + result
        number /= base
    } while number > 0
    return result
}

numberToCustomRadix(3, alphabet: "012") // 10
numberToCustomRadix(4, alphabet: "abc") // bb
numberToCustomRadix(5, alphabet: "%#9") // #9
```

Note that the problem with a custom alphabet is the fact that it's hard to guarantee at compile time that the alphabet contains distinct characters. E.g. an "aaabbbccc" alphabet will generate all kind of conversion problems.

---

Comment: @Jonas0000 it's possible to "decode", but that's another question, and on SO we usually don't address multiple issues in one question, especially if the other issues are not specified in the question (but be careful with that, asking multiple questions in the same post can get your post closed for being too broad)

Comment: If you want unique characters, require them to pass a `Set`.

Comment: @vacawama a `Set` will resolve the uniqueness problem, however the unique-ing will still happen at runtime, which might result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I also just thought that `Set`s are unordered, so that won't work. NVM.

Comment: @vacawama oh, yeah, forgot about that :)

Comment: You can use `NSOrderedSet`

Comment: `let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: Array(alphabet))
    let base = orderedSet.count
    var number = number
    var result: [Character] = []
    repeat {
        result.insert(orderedSet.object(at: number % base) as! Character, at: 0)
        number /= base
    } while number > 0
    return String(result)`