# How to convert AnyBase to Base10?

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, radix

I found [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724055/custom-radix-columns-special-characters/) to encode a **Base10-String** with to a **custom BaseString**:

```
func stringToCustomBase(encode: Int, alphabet: String) -> String {
    var base = alphabet.count, int = encode, result = ""
    repeat {
        let index = alphabet.index(alphabet.startIndex, offsetBy: (int % base))
        result = [alphabet[index]] + result
        int /= base
    } while (int > 0)
    return result
}
```

... calling it with this lines:

```
let encoded = stringToCustomBase(encode: 9291, alphabet: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")
print(encoded)
```

---

The encoding above works pretty good. But what about decoding the encoded string?

So because I got no idea how to decode a (in this case `Base62` *[alphabet.count=62]*) to a human readable string (in this case [*Base10*]) any help would be super appreciated.

---

PS: (A full code solution is not required, I can also come up with some kind of `pseudo-code` or maybe just a `few-lines of code`)

---

This is what I've tried so far:

```
func reVal(num: Int) -> Character {
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 9) {
        return Character("\(num)")
    }
    return Character("\(num - 10)A");
}


func convertBack() {
    var index = 0;
    let encoded = "w2RDn3"
    var decoded = [Character]()
    var inputNum = encoded.count
    repeat {
        index+=1
        decoded[index] = reVal(num: inputNum % 62)
        //encoded[index] = reVal(inputNum % 62);
        inputNum /= 62;

    }  while (inputNum > 0)
    print(decoded);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the original algorithm you need to iterate through each character of the encoded string, find the location of that character within the alphabet, and calculate the new result.

Here are both methods and some test code:

```
func stringToCustomBase(encode: Int, alphabet: String) -> String {
    var base = alphabet.count, string = encode, result = ""
    repeat {
        let index = alphabet.index(alphabet.startIndex, offsetBy: (string % base))
        result = [alphabet[index]] + result
        string /= base
    } while (string > 0)
    return result
}

func customBaseToInt(encoded: String, alphabet: String) -> Int? {
    let base = alphabet.count
    var result = 0
    for ch in encoded {
        if let index = alphabet.index(of: ch) {
            let mult = result.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: base)
            if (mult.overflow) {
                 return nil
            } else {
                let add = mult.partialValue.addingReportingOverflow(alphabet.distance(from: alphabet.startIndex, to: index))
                if (add.overflow) {
                    return nil
                } else {
                    result = add.partialValue
                }
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return result
}


let startNum = 234567
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
let codedNum = stringToCustomBase(encode: startNum, alphabet: alphabet)
let origNun = customBaseToInt(encoded: codedNum, alphabet: alphabet)
```

I made the `customBaseToInt` method return an optional result in case there are characters in the encoded value that are not in the provided alphabet.

Comment: An additional option is to use `multipliedReportingOverflow` and `addingReportingOverflow` to detect a possible overflow (and return nil instead of crashing).

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. This was **exactly** the solution I'd loved to see.

Comment: If the two methods are used in pairs, overflow won't be an issue. Start with an `Int`. Encode it using `stringToCustomBase`. If you then decode it using `customBaseToInt` and the same alphabet, you get the original `Int`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Sure, it was just a suggestion. (And with your argument you need not check the validity of the character either, and could return a non-optional.)

Comment: @MartinR Since I never used those methods, I updated the code to safely calculate the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via `reduce`:

```
enum RadixDecodingError: Error {
    case invalidCharacter
    case overflowed
}

func customRadixToInt(str: String, alphabet: String) throws -> Int {
    return try str.reduce(into: 0) {
        guard let digitIndex = alphabet.index(of: $1) else {
            throw RadixDecodingError.invalidCharacter
        }
        let multiplied = $0.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: alphabet.count)
        guard !multiplied.overflow else {
            throw RadixDecodingError.overflowed
        }
        let added = multiplied.partialValue.addingReportingOverflow(alphabet.distance(from: alphabet.startIndex, to: digitIndex))
        guard !added.overflow else {
            throw RadixDecodingError.overflowed
        }
        $0 = added.partialValue
    }
}
```

I used the exception throwing mechanism so that the caller can distinguish between invalid characters or overflow errors.

Comment: Why do you reverse the input string?

Comment: @MartinR to be honest, I'm not sure :P. I added it while doing some more attempts to convert, however that was a mistake, so I removed it from the answer.